# Automatic update of Windows application(click once) while publishing on other computer's IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I am publishing my windows application(using ) on share drive and want to give Users facility to update there applications automaticaly. 
But in "Click Once" I need to specify Installation Folder URL(My Computer does not have IIS on it).
So I am trying to publish my application on other computer's IIS(in the network).

I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation Folder URL does not have to be an actual URL or website.  It can be a UNC path like \ComputerName\SharedDrive\MyApplication

So in this case IIS is not needed at all.